# aws ssm agent - AWS-RunPowerShellScript - how to run the script as admin user of a active directory

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I have an active directory created

I have created a `EC2` windows instance and is joined with the active directory created above.

Also the windows `EC2` instance is joined with the `ssm`.

Now I have a powershell script on the EC2 instance, which I want to run using `ssm`.

the ssm-agent is running as the user `nt authority\system` on the windows EC2 instance instead of the running as admin user of Active directory

the below is the boto3 code

```
# running the command on windows Ec2
command="WhoAmI"

ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm',region_name='us-west-2')

ssm_response = ssm_client.send_command(
                DocumentName="AWS-RunPowerShellScript", 
                InstanceIds=[instance_id],
                Comment='Checking the user',
                TimeoutSeconds=600, 
                Parameters={"commands":[command]}
            )
```

the output of command is

`nt authority\system`

instead i am expecting the ssm-agent will run as

`admin\test.somedomain.com`  where `test.somedomain.com` is my active directory domain name, which is joined with the EC2 instance.